# check if website is online - problems with postback

Tags: c#, javascript, webforms

I've got a webpage that people in my company are filling in using mobile handsets. Only problem is, if they move out of a signal area, then when they try and update their work the page will go to a "page not found" and they'll lose the work they've filled in.

I'm trying to remedy this and, at the moment, have this solution:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["Online"] = 0;
    CheckConnect();
    if ((int)Session["Online"] == 1) { Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('You are currently online')", true); }
    if ((int)Session["Online"] == 0) { Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('You are currently offline')", true); }
}

protected void CheckConnect()
{
    System.Uri Url = new System.Uri("http://www.mypage.com/pixel.jpg?" + DateTime.Now);
    System.Net.WebRequest WebReq;
    System.Net.WebResponse Resp;
    WebReq = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(Url);
    try
    {
        Resp = WebReq.GetResponse();
        Resp.Close();
        WebReq = null;
        Session["Online"] = 1;
    }
    catch
    {
        WebReq = null;
        Session["Online"] = 0;
    }
}
```

Now, this will check if the pixel file at www.mypage.com exists (no, that's not actually my page, I've substituted it for this example) and, if so, it returns a 0, if not a 1. Which is fine and dandy.

However, pressing the button causes the page to be reloaded. Then, if it's offline, it does the usual "page not found" business. My button code is here:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
```

Basically, I want it to not reload the page if we're offline (or indeed if we are online, as the code that does the updating handles that part anyway).

EDIT - alright, different approach now. Doing this entirely through javascript using the following:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="ifServerOnline()" Text="Button" />

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function ifServerOnline(ifOnline, ifOffline)
            {
                var img = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("img"));
                img.onload = function ()
                {
                    ifOnline && ifOnline.constructor == Function && ifOnline();
                };
                img.onerror = function ()
                {
                    ifOffline && ifOffline.constructor == Function && ifOffline();
                };
                img.src = "http://www.mypage.com/pixel.jpg?" + Date.now;
            }

            ifServerOnline(function ()
            {
                return confirm('Online');
            },
            function ()
            {
                return confirm('Offline');
            });
        </script>
```

Unfortunately still causing a page refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do postback to the server when you offline.
No way to do it..

But maybe you can do that's with javascript.. try this way.

Comment: So when I call my c# codebehind, it's automatically on the server (I guess this would be the runat server part - d'oh)? The c# part has to be called from the server I guess.

Answer (score 4):

In your page's javascript assign form `onsubmit` event handler, where you cancel default submit. Also, in this event handler, issue an ajax request to the server with a very brief response. In `onsuccess` event handler of this ajax request - resubmit the form, in `onerror` handler - tell the user that they lost connection to server.

Answer (score 0):

Managed it with this...

```
        <asp:Button ID="btnRouteC" runat="server" OnClientClick="return ifServerOnlineA(ifServerOnlineA1, ifServerOfflineA1);" Text="Route" Width="45%" />

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function ifServerOnlineA(ifOnline, ifOffline)
            {
                var img = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("img"));
                img.onload = function ()
                {
                    ifOnline && ifOnline.constructor == Function && ifOnline();
                };
                img.onerror = function ()
                {
                    ifOffline && ifOffline.constructor == Function && ifOffline();
                };
                img.src = "http://www.myserver.com/pixel.jpg?" + Date.now;
                return false;
            }

            function ifServerOnlineA1()
            {
                document.getElementById('btnRoute').click();
                return false;
            }
            function ifServerOfflineA1()
            {
                alert("There is no connection at the moment. Please try again later.");
                return false;
            }
        </script>
```

As Itiel said, it won't work through the codebehind but will through the Javascript.